# Freemarker syntax for a form for a collection of objects (Spring 3 MVC)

Tags: spring-mvc, freemarker

I have a command bean (`FooList`) which has a property which is a collection (a `List` of `Foo` beans).

I'm trying to create a form which can edit all the `Foo`s at once. I have found many examples of how to do this using JSP, but I'm having trouble translating these to Freemarker syntax.

In my Freemarker template, I can easily iterate over the collection:

```
[#list fooList.foos as foo]
...
[/#list]
```

I can also refer to a particular `Foo` by index:

```
[@spring.bind "fooList.foos[0].name" /]
<input type="text" name="${spring.status.expression}" value="${spring.status.value?default('')}"/>
```

However, I haven't yet worked out how I can do both at the same time, to bind all the `Foo`s to form elements.

Here's one naïve attempt which failed:

```
[#list fooList.foos as foo]
    [@spring.bind "fooList.foos[foo_index].name" /]
    ...
[/#list]
```

(On its own, `${foo_index}` works inside the loop.)

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just had the same problem. This worked for me:

```
[#list fooList.foos as foo]
  <#assign item>fooList.foos[${foo_index}].name</#assign>
  [@spring.bind item /]
  ...
[/#list]
```

Comment: On a side note, I find Spring's Freemarker support somewhat buggy sometimes. Which really is a shame, as IMHO I regard Freemarker far more advanced and far more simple to use in general when compared to JSPs

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
[#list fooList.foos as foo] 
    [@spring.bind "foo.name" /] 
    ... 
[/#list]
```

The foo in that example will reference each item in the list one by one, according to the freemarker documentation on [the list directive](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_directive_list.html).

Comment: Thanks, but that was the very first thing I tried. If you're sure that this is the correct solution then I can provide the tracebacks (but not right now).

Comment: Sorry but I can't actually try it, I don't see why that wouldn't work though. Have you seen this example, (14.4.5.2) ? http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/view.html

Comment: Yes, I have seen that example, but it only shows a simple example in Freemarker syntax. I am looking for an example of binding a collection of arbitrary size.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be as follows:

```
[#list fooList.foos as foo]
    [@spring.bind "fooList.foos[" + foo_index + "].name" /]
    ...
[/#list]
```