# Validation of @spring.formInput in #list iterator

Tags: java, spring, validation, freemarker

I have a freemarker page, where I need to post an Entry from a list of Entries.

In order to overcome problems with spring.formInput and freemarker lists ([see problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8006163/spring-forminput-in-list-iterator)) I construct the html forms in the following way:

```
<#list entries as entry>
    <@form.form method="POST" commandName="receiver">
        <@spring.formInput "entries.entry[${entry_index}].name"/>
        <@spring.formInput "entries.entry[${entry_index}].value"/>
    </@form.form>
</#list>
```

My Controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(method=POST, params="save") 
public String save(@ModelAttribute(value="entries") @Valid Entries entries, BindingResult result, Model model){
    /*notice, we always get the last item in the list, since the entries  "carries" the index of the form through, and  creates
     * null-object in the first n places
    */ 
    int index = entries.size()-1;
    Entry entry = entries.get(index);
    if (!result.hasErrors()) {
        formService.save(entry);
    }

    return "";
}
```

Unfortunately the @Valid annotations causes error whenever I post an Entry apart from the first in list.

This happens because spring automatically populates my list with null values up till the current index.

- I would prefer to post an Entry instead of Entries, but I do not
  think this can be done.
- Alternatively, how do I stop the validation from taking place on
  the first n-1 entries in list?
- Or, can I somehow test which object in list (index) caused the
  error, so that I can just avoid errors from the first n-1 entries?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue before some months. But I had problem in using the **LazyList**. May be you will find your answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614718/how-to-validate-dynamically-generated-fields-server-side). Hope this helps you.